# Enable a Plugin for Oh my Zsh in Docker

Tags: zsh, docker, oh-my-zsh

I trying to install the **symfony2** and **git** plugin for **zsh** in my **docker** container.

```
FROM php:7-fpm

# Install Packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim zsh git   
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli zip mbstring 

# Instal Oh my Zsh
RUN bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
RUN sed -i -- 's/robbyrussell/wezm+/g' /root/.zshrc # Other awesome theme: random kafeitu sonicradish wezm+
RUN echo "plugins=(git symfony2)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

But the auto completion does not work. It's like the plugin has not been installed.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You append plugins=(git symfony2) to your zshrc, which will then look like this:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
plugins=(git symfony2)
```

For the plugins to get loaded, you need to define the array *before* including oh-my-zsh.sh, i.e. swap the lines above. Instead of doing echo and append, you can echo to file(or use ADD), concat the original zshrc and move the new file to ~/.zshrc